# Extract array in string rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3

My string is

```
"[1,2,3]"
```

I want to get output in the below format

```
[1,2,3]
```

I want to extract array present in my string.

Comment: Your question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526219/how-do-i-convert-this-ruby-string-into-an-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just parse it with `JSON.parse` method like this ;

```
JSON.parse("[1,2,3]")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eval`:

try:

```
eval("[1,2,3]")
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You shouldn't suggest to use `eval` without warning about the risks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try it:

```
"[1,2,3]".scan(/\w/).map{|x| x.to_i}
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.